# Custom NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm having some issue with my custom NavigationDrawer. Indeed, it opens and closes fine but it doesn't show the listview...
Since the logcat doesn't indicate any error, it's quite difficult to find the mistake for me so maybe another pair of eyes will spot it easily !

**ObjectDrawerItem:**

```
  public class ObjectDrawerItem {

  public int icon;
  public String name;

  public ObjectDrawerItem(int icon, String name) {
      this.icon = icon;
      this.name = name;
  }
}
```

**DrawerItemCustomAdapter:**

```
public class DrawerItemCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ObjectDrawerItem> {

  Context mContext;
  int mLayoutResourceId;
  ObjectDrawerItem mData[] = null;

  public DrawerItemCustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, ObjectDrawerItem[] data) {

      super(context, resource);
      this.mLayoutResourceId = resource;
      this.mContext = context;
      this.mData = data;
  }



  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

      View listItem = convertView;
      ObjectDrawerItem folder = mData[position];


      LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
      listItem = inflater.inflate(mLayoutResourceId, parent, false);

      ImageView imageViewIcon = (ImageView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.imageViewIcon);
      TextView textViewName = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);

      imageViewIcon.setImageResource(folder.icon);
      textViewName.setText(folder.name);

      return listItem;
  }

}
```

**NavigationDrawerHelper:**

```
public class NavigationDrawerHelper{

  private String[] mNavigationDrawerItemTitles;
  DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
  ListView mDrawerListView;
  private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

  public void init(Activity activity, ListView.OnItemClickListener listener) {

      mNavigationDrawerItemTitles = activity.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navigation_drawer_items_array);
      mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
      mDrawerListView = (ListView) activity.findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

      // list the drawer items
      ObjectDrawerItem[] drawerItem = new ObjectDrawerItem[3];

      drawerItem[0] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_action_copy, "Create");
      drawerItem[1] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_action_refresh, "Read");
      drawerItem[2] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_action_share, "Help");


      DrawerItemCustomAdapter adapter = new DrawerItemCustomAdapter(activity, R.layout.listview_item_row, drawerItem);
      mDrawerListView.setAdapter(adapter);
      mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(listener);


      mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
      mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(0, true);

      setupActionBar(activity);

  }
}
```

And in my **Activity (implements ListView.OnItemClickListener)**'s onCreate() I call the NavigationDrawerHelper init():

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    updateWeather();

    mNavigationDrawerHelper = new NavigationDrawerHelper();
    mNavigationDrawerHelper.init(this,this);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, it looks like the issue likes with your adapter, which extends an ArrayAdapter. Extend and use a BaseAdapter instead.

The problem lies in that you pass in the data, but the ArrayAdapter itself doesn't know the size of the data [and thus doesn't know how many rows to create and therefore won't call on your getView()]. There may be a way to further extend and modify an ArrayAdapter to set the data up yourself, but at that point you're practically using a BaseAdapter.

[Also, this is assuming your xml is well-formed and perfect]

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped